# Quartz.NET Setting up Job Executions Externally

Tags: c#, quartz.net

Currently, I am able to use Quartz.NET Jobs executions with Triggers saved in a local appsettings.json file. This currently run off a single machine. I use ADOJobStore to persist the jobs in a database. I use QuartzHostedService to launch the app and run as a Windows Service.

However, I want to move away from setting up the job triggers in the appsettings & use SilkierQuartz to create Jobs and set up Triggers (and change them remotely). I would like the application run without loading config from appsettings - but run whatever is set in the database.

```
services.UseQuartzHostedService()
.RegiserJob<JobOne>()
.RegiserJob<JobTwo>()
.RegiserJob<JobThree>();
```

Will I need to restart the service if the trigger changes?

Or the biggest question - does this require a solution that is beyond Quartz?

cheers